# Docker client version different than docker server version after update

Tags: docker

I have docker desktop installed on window 10. I recently updated docker which updated the docker server to the latest version 20.10.5 but now the docker client version doesn't match the docker server version. I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling docker but I got the same version as earlier. Is there any way I can update the client to the same version as the server version?

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.3
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.10
 Git commit:        2355349d-
 Built:             10/14/2019 16:41:26
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64      
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community      
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12) 
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021    
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score 0):

In docker desktop, The Docker Desktop installation includes Docker Engine, Docker CLI client, Docker Compose, Notary, Kubernetes, and Credential Helper. So either upgrade the Docker Desktop, if you have an older version you would like to use then, you may need to uninstall current version of Docker Desktop you have and then install the earlier version.

All containers should be stopped and the all docker services also, and then start the service.